# Override Function in Member Object

Tags: c++, oop

Disclaimer: I'm a long time C programmer moving into C++, so it's very likely/possible there is a better way to do this.

I would like to create a `class A` with 1 to N members of `class B`.  In most cases, I'm fine calling `class B`'s member functions.  However, in some cases I would like to override a member function **in** `class B`.  Is there an elegant way to do this without having to create a derived class from `class B` every time?

Here is an example:

```
using namespace std;
#include <iostream>

class B
{
public:
    void print();
};

void B::print()
{
    cout << "B::print" << endl;
}

class A
{
public:
    B b;
    B bprime;
};

int main()
{
    A a;
    a.b.print();
    a.bprime.print();
    return 0;
}
```

Is there a way to override the `print()` function in `bprime` or otherwise change it?  In C, I would have left `class B` as a struct and used function pointers, but I'd like to avoid that here.

Comment: Deriving from the base class *is* the elegant way.

Comment: There might be a better way of doing things for your case, but we'd need to know what the classes represent.

Comment: (1) How do you want to decide when to call "prime" print? Depending on which instance, as in your example? -> inheritance is the way. On another condition? let us know. (2) do you have a vector/container of them?  in this case -> smart pointers, virtual functions.  **tl;dr** we need more details.

Comment: *Is there a way to override the print() function in bprime or otherwise change it?* That depends on how flexible you need to be to print the objects.

Comment: In my specific case, class A represents a state in a state machine and class B represents possible actions.  In general, class B would define the actions as NOPs.  But in some cases, I would like the object of type A to override part of the action.

Comment: @peterchen I would always call `print()` for a class B member of class A, but depending on the instance of A I would like to be able to override the behavior of print().  Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use std::function to simulate polymorphism.

```
class B
{
    public:
    std::function<_FUNCTION_SIGNATURE_HERE_> print;
};
```

then you can always override print member in an instance of B

```
   a.bprime.print = SomeOTherFunctionWithSameSignature;
```

and from this moment on bprime will behave as if it was a different subclass in a hierarchy. Everything will work the same, except this particular function you changed.

Of course you will have to set initial behavior of print member in your constructor.

Comment: How is `SomeOTherFunctionWithSameSignature` declared?  Is it a member of class A or is it a static function?

Comment: It can be pretty much anything. free function, member function... std::function hides away all dependencies. it's a really, _really_ cool feature of new c++.  If it is a free function you can just assign it to your print function object and all will work. if it is a class member you will have to bind std::bind actual object to it and assign the result of a bind. Just read std::function docs

Comment: Wow, that would be great.  I'd really like it if I could have a.bprime.print = class A member function.  That was I could call A.b.print() for the default behavior, but A.bprime.print() could really be a call to A.specialPrint() if necessary.

Comment: possible, you'd just have to std::bind an object of type A while assigning. a.bprime.print = std::bind(&A::specialPrint, a, std::placeholders::_1....X); placeholders are for parameter of print function

Comment: though I have to warn you that using print function of wrapper class in a wrapped class reeks of design mistake somewhere

Comment: I know.  :)  This all made sense in the context of C with structures, but it's clearly not translating to C++ well.  I'm sure there's a different design pattern I should be using.